# Quel est le sens de « donc » dans la phrase « ne te préoccupe pas donc de ça » ?

Tags: sens, adverbes

Le mot « donc » peut-il être supprimé de cette phrase ? Quelle est sa fonction ?

Comment: Es-tu sûr que tu n'as pas lu ou entendu « ne te préoccupes donc pas de ça » plutôt ?

Comment: Oui, je suis un étudiant étranger et donc il y a encore beaucoup de phrases que je ne les ai jamais vues. (Honnêtement, je ne suis pas sûr de ce que ma réponse-là soit correcte à la grammaire ?)

Comment: Venant du nord, « ne te préoccupes donc pas de ça » serait l'expression que j'utiliserais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Donc* ici est utilisé en tant qu'**adverbe** et modifie le sens du verbe, il renforce la demande qui est faite. On pourrait dire aussi :

> Ne te préoccupe vraiment pas de ça !

Donc, le supprimer ne change pas le sens de la phrase en soi, mais sa présence rend la demande plus insistante.

*Donc* peut aussi être conjonction, comme dans la phrase précédente où il marque un rapport de conséquence entre son sens et le fait qu'il puisse être supprimé.